# unable to override a ribbon border color

Tags: master-page, page-layout, css

I have a ribbon with green boarder , inside SharePoint server 2013 as follow:- 
[image]

The ribbon has three css classes , and inside my custom CSS, i define the following CSS rules:-

```
.ms-cui-tabContainer ms-cui-tabContainer-gr  {
    border-color:#008CD2 !important;
}
.ms-cui-tabBody ms-cui-tabBody-gr{
    border-color:#008CD2 !important;

}
.ms-cui-ribbon{
    border-color:#008CD2 !important;
}
```

but still the ribbon have a green boarder instead of blue border .

Can anyone advice please?

Answer (score 0):

- fix css rule

  your css rule is not correct:

  1. missing `.` before `ms-cui-tabBody-gr`
  2. remove space between classes: .ms-cui-tabBody and .ms-cui-tabBody-gr

  the right code is

  ```
  .ms-cui-tabBody.ms-cui-tabBody-gr{
       border-color:/*any color*/ !important;
  }
  ```

  the best, set **top** and **bottom** border

  `.ms-cui-tabBody-gr, .ms-cui-ct-topBar-gr{border-color:/*any color*/ !important;}`
- put your css after all css links of SP